# How to pause the timer when the time is getting to the exact target time?

Tags: c#, winforms

In a dateTimePicker1 I'm setting hours,minutes,second in whole digits I mean: 05:11:07
05 = hours , 11 = minutes and 07 = seconds

but the timer is increasing up/down with milliseconds digits.

for example I set the target time to 00:00:05 and after 5 seconds the timer is stopping.
but the time in the timer is not exactly 5 seconds.

[image: timer]

the time is: 00:00:05.018

I want the timer to be with digits after the point on the seconds.
but in the dateTimePicker I want the target time to be without digits after the seconds.

the question is if it's logic and to leave it as it is, or should I make somehow that the timer must get to exactly 00:00:05 and then stop on the target?

This is the timerTarget method:

```
private void timeTarget(TimeSpan ctimeSpan)
        {
            if (dateTimePicker1.Value.Hour == ctimeSpan.Hours
                && dateTimePicker1.Value.Minute == ctimeSpan.Minutes
                && dateTimePicker1.Value.Second == ctimeSpan.Seconds
                && timeTargetchkbox.Checked == true)
            {
                if (btnPause.Text == "PAUSE")
                {
                    btnPause.Text = "CONTINUE";
                    watch.Stop();
                    timer1.Enabled = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (btnStart.Text == "STOP")
                {
                    btnPause.Text = "PAUSE";
                    watch.Start();
                    timer1.Enabled = true;
                }
            }
            timeTargetchkboxState();
        }
```

and the dateTimePicker value changed event:

```
private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btnStart.Focus();
            timeTarget(ctimeSpan);
            optionsfile.SetKey("timetargetvalue", dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString());
        }
```

the whole code in form1 is a bit long so I can't put here all the code so I put it in pastebin.com

https://pastebin.com/t2hYLyrC

Comment: FYI, *"digits after the point on the seconds"* are called milliseconds

Comment: It is not clear to me what the actual question is. Windows timers have a limited accuracy, so you will never get a timer to take exactly 5s, for that you need a real time OS. So if you want to fix your display, just clamp the shown time, so if it is larger than 5s, show 5s exactly.

Comment: Or you could build a custom timer class that increments a long value from 0 which should be the millisecond value to use for computations in your code. That would stop dead at 0 but a stop watch will not stop exactly at , I have tried multiple time and it either stops just before 5 or after 5